# Type-checking the keys of a const literal without losing the type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a constant that references keys of an interface.
I want this constant to be type-checked to be sure that the keys are properly named, and I also want them to be typed as literals.

If I do the following:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  keyA: string;
  keyB: string;
}

export const MY_KEYS: Record<string, keyof MyInterface> = {
  CONSTANT_KEY_A: 'keyA',
  CONSTANT_KEY_B: 'keyB',
} as const;

MY_KEYS.CONSTANT_KEY_A
```

then `MY_KEYS.CONSTANT_KEY_A` is of type `'keyA' | 'keyB'`. But I want it to be `'keyA'`!

If I remove `Record<string, keyof MyInterface>` then it will work, but then my keys are no longer type checked to be in the keys of MyInterface.

Any idea on how I can achieve that?

I could for example add a second dead variable that does the Record check and keep my first one only with `as const` and not casted as Record, but it's pretty verbose and not really clear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often in cases like this I introduce a helper function which checks that a value is assignable to a type without widening the value to that type. The general version of the helper function looks like this:

```
const checkType = <T>() => <U extends T>(u: U) => u;
```

And then to have it check a particular type you call it and manually specify that type:

```
const checkKeys = checkType<Record<string, keyof MyInterface>>();
```

Now you have a function which will only accept values of the right type and will give you the expected error when you do something wrong:

```
export const MY_KEYS = checkKeys({
  CONSTANT_KEY_A: 'keyA',
  CONSTANT_KEY_B: 'keyB',
  // CONSTANT_KEY_C: 'keyC', // error! '"keyC"' is not assignable to  '"keyA" | "keyB"'.
})
```

but the output of the function is not widened, as desired:

```
MY_KEYS.CONSTANT_KEY_A // "keyA"
```

Note that you don't even need `as const` because the compiler sees that you want to interpret the object literal as assignable to `Record<string, keyof MyInterface>` and therefore does not widen the literal string values to `string`.  You can still use `as const` if it helps you in other ways, though.

---

Conceptually this isn't really different from your "dead variable" idea, and certainly at runtime `(() => u => u)()(someValue)` is a weird way of writing `someValue`.  But without a built-in "verify assignability without widening" operator in TypeScript (like maybe [microsoft/TypeScript#30809](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30809)?), this is the best way I know how to do it in general.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=3.9.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkBrCdAQQC5kBnMKUAcwG4TzKAhOx5kOyIBfZESIIA9iEbIEACwgIyAFXQAHFAF5kAHhUA+ABQBKZFoN6AqsggAPSCAAm9ZIaMBXOlbMXkHjikZMDlFZQBpSlcdBSVVDQhdACUlSSgnXX5WABoudEkYNCwcWEQIA2MTDiJ7dTSQoNlUAE0AfXCAUWaAZXNQuMj0eiNiUgBhAHkAOW6VKimVdq7W2mQAcgpqNezOSZm5haW23nXN7m3OAHpL5D3Z+cXOtrG6Dcox7eRr2ygoNIBCdYAIk2YyBa2QwFcIEkITg9HowBYIDgACMADYoMCSUhrEGUKhA5AAH2Q+PQ3HBADoRCZxC0jt0qXcDo9llQvjdyYSgA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But it doesn't work  The type of `MY_KEYS.CONSTANT_KEY_A` is `"keyA" | "keyB"`...

Comment: Sorry, the `"keyC"` example was causing that; the error made the compiler give up on type inference.  I commented it out and you'll see that the value is of type `"keyA"` now.

Comment: Fantastic, it works indeed! Many thanks, it fits my needs perfectly 

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on typescript 4.9.5 or higher, you can use `satisfies` ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)):

```js
export const MY_KEYS = {
  CONSTANT_KEY_A: 'keyA',
  CONSTANT_KEY_B: 'keyB',
} as const satisfies Record<string, keyof MyInterface>;

MY_KEYS.CONSTANT_KEY_A
// (property) CONSTANT_KEY_A: "keyA"
```