# Is it possible to constrain the values of an object literal while still being able to infer the exact keys of that object later?

Tags: typescript

I'm running into a problem where trying to use a Typescript type with an index signature to constrain the *values* of an object literal destroys the ability, later on, to correctly infer the exact *keys* of that object. I'm wondering if there's something clever I could do to work around this (I'm not wedded to index signatures), or if I'm hitting a limitation of the language.

For context, I'm writing a function (`createStore`) that accepts an `actions` parameter that is an object containing some number of `StoreAction` functions as values. The `createStore` function returns a `store` object that contains (among other things) those same actions. When I use the `store`, I want TypeScript to yell at me if I call an an action that doesn't exist (i.e. it isn't a key on the `actions` object that was used to create the `store`).

You can see [the example below in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysD2AnCBBAxsAlvAdgHjgENgIA+KAXigAoBnYYiALlgZIEpLyiSBuAKH6hIUAGqEANgFcItFMnRZctPABUANK0bkqAb35QoAbQDWEEFEw4oZkPABmUVQF0WcJKgzZ8PMgIC+Avz2UjheuFBoyIzuyARsEJqK3rRQEAAeJDgAJqni0rLynko4KsnKmr6kpNSE4aUs5aWa9IxuCZz6hgD03VAAktbAABbQ0RKWALZgEhCTEDhs3poA7hAA5MhQAEZSmBLZVgDmUCPQ9B6ahDk7Voc4J2dQdSVQIWElqQino1AXyAA6AxQZDAKSIay6Z71WgtBJQQL8fyCXqotHojEY-i9JzDTCpFZIEypQipDKQDAQbJAzG0um9QTCaAAWRAsQgvkoUCh9ng8BY9EQxwRKL6ADl4CQWDh4KdwNBrjKlsooBEngAiF4pdWq7YAKwgGCgEkwJEQkn4aGUwGhny5XSgkxATQAjCw6AkWKz2b5OBRyFDugAqKDZWW0eDzR3wQ72TBoYgpU7hhIAtNQIN9UHg6ytEgI9RIwRW0o2p3srlRCAxBDIWowzQ8vksdXbQiIdX+dgCcu1iAArXKAFO13UJv8qCtwgAL07nBxAHUibDnmT0hSSNl+L2PAOYQCrAA3SSYbJNMdvZuTtuzrtQHGqGBQACiiEQSCua43VME2Pp-7RP9cXxUN4FkKAlSgQlEBMVcBnWbJjUwMwmD-ACANFAZnmAEhpk3ZMoKFfNCDlEQRmISJrXNKwvl+Y8ClVRxNRhHV4H1Q0bRNM1JELHEIx+aApFoCBEEia4oCOCAbXsCAqTbNBYKsE0cGgTBHDOCxJkIMxnkdfEGB0qwBNtbw3lCeo-kwI4cGIcFZCBJlWA8JoVCqe1gSMGz5gFYAhQeVwnIUep4m0IsgIlKUoFCE0dMIbZ4EPRIfhAtiDSNLiRMkSxUiOTBEuscS7gySzrNswFLWtEzlAAJnaZyYTwb0+zcvRgRHeo3T+eF-W5e8QzDP5I2gSYYzU+NExVb4837dNMxBKScy6xgRWRCrS0dNk+2qytohIdl60+arG0vCcpw7Ltt02jxqr3T5h2dDqL15U6bzne8+iXGCV1JNJ1w4n8d2QG7B1KA8cHo09z3HFtXrvHEJScJ9X3fRAAEIgA).

Here is a simplified version of the `createStore` function:

```
type StoreAction<State> = (state: State) => State;

type ValuesAreActions<T, State> = {
  [key in keyof T]: StoreAction<State>;
};

function createStore<State, Actions extends ValuesAreActions<Actions, State>>(actions: Actions, state: State) {
  // In the real implementation, we're building the store, and binding the action functions to the store.
  return { actions, state };
}
```

Using it this way works fine:

```
type MyStoreState = { foo: string }

// Note: no type annotations on the "actions" object literal
const actions = {
  myAction1: (state: MyStoreState) => { /* do some modifications to state... */ return state },
}

const myStore = createStore(actions, { foo: "bar"});
myStore.actions.myAction1({ foo: "baz"}) // Works, as expected
myStore.actions.invalidAction({ foo: "baz"}) // TS Error, as expected
```

This does not work as I'd like:

```
// I attempted to write a type that constrains the value of "actions" object literal,
// so the user can get feedback inline if they make a mistake in the action function signatures.
type StoreActions<State> = {
  [name: string]: StoreAction<State>
}

// Note: unlike above, this object literal is given an index signature.
const actions2: StoreActions<MyStoreState> = {
  myAction1: state => { /* do some modifications to state... */ return state }
}

const myStore2 = createStore(actions2, { foo: "bar"})
myStore2.actions.myAction1({ foo: "baz"}) // Works, as expected
myStore2.actions.invalidAction({ foo: "baz"}) // No TS Error!
```

Comment: Please consider editing this code so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) which demonstrates your issue without introducing unrelated problems.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362083/type-checking-the-keys-of-a-const-literal-without-losing-the-type) but I'm not 100% sure it's the same issue without usable example code.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think this is a different question from [the one you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362083/type-checking-the-keys-of-a-const-literal-without-losing-the-type). I'll work on removing the pseudo-code from the examples, and getting a typescript-playground example linked.

Comment: I edited the post and the example code to make sure it will run unmodified, and added a link to the same code running in the TypeScript playground.

Comment: Check [this code](https://tsplay.dev/vW41Bw), where in line 38 or so I take the answer from the other question and translate it here.  If this works for you, then this is a duplicate; the issue is "how do I ensure that a value is assignable to a type without widening it to that type and forgetting about its specific structure", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TypeScript 4.9+ will have exactly the feature I was asking for - the `satisfies` operator (see [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator)).

For example:

```
// This type is meant to constrain the value of the "actions" object (same as above)
type StoreActions<State> = {
  [name: string]: StoreAction<State>
}

// This is the "old" way of doing it (same as above). Assigning a general type to "actions2" hides the more specific aspects of the type.
const actions2: StoreActions<MyStoreState> = {
  myAction1: state => { /* do some modifications to state... */ return state }
}

// This uses the new "satisfies" operator to help catch errors on the object literal, while still enabling type inference down the line.
const actions3 = {
  myAction1: state => { /* do some modifications to state... */ return state }
} satisfies StoreActions<MyStoreState>;


const myStore2 = createStore(actions2, { foo: "bar"});
const myStore3 = createStore(actions3, { foo: "bar"});


myStore2.actions.myAction1({ foo: "baz"}) // Works, as expected.
myStore3.actions.myAction1({ foo: "baz"}) // Works, as expected.

// @ts-expect-error
myStore2.actions.invalidAction({ foo: "baz"}) // No TS Error!
// @ts-expect-error
myStore3.actions.invalidAction({ foo: "baz"}) // Property 'invalidAction' does not exist on type '{ myAction1: (state: MyStoreState) => MyStoreState; }'
```

See [this example in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/C4TwDgpgBAysD2AnCBBAxsAlvAdgHjgENgIA+KAXigAoBnYYiALlgZIEpLyiSBuAWABQQ0JCgA1QgBsArhFopk6LLlp4AKgBpWjclQDeQqFADaAawggomHFAsh4AMyjqAuizhJUGbPh5kBQQBfQKFHGRwfXCg0ZEZPZAI2CG1lX1ooCAAPEhwAEwzJWXlFbxUcNTTVbX9SUmpCKIqWKortekYPZM5DQWMAen6oAElbYAALaDipawBbMCkIWYgcNl9tAHcIAHJkKAAjGUwpPJsAcygJ6HovbUJ8g5tTnAurqEbyqHDI8oyES8mUBuyAAdEYoMhgDJELZ9O8mrR2skoCEhEEhEJBi5xpg-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-xOC3KBha8fxeBRbYgA)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I totally understand what you're trying to do, but here's a 'throw spaghetti at a wall' suggestion..

Make the key type of `StoreActions` a generic parameter:

```
type StoreActions<KeyType extends string, State> = {
  [key in KeyType]: StoreAction<State>
}
```

Now pass the allowable keys as a generic parameter:

```
const actions2: StoreActions<
  "myAction1" | "myAction2",
  MyStoreState
> = {
  myAction1: state => { /* do some modifications to state... */ return state },
  myAction2: state => { /* I'm adding a second valid key here... */ return state }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysD2AnCBBAxsAlvAdgHjgENgIA+KAXigAoBnYYiALlgZIEpLyiSBuAKH6hIUAGqEANgFcItFMnRZctPABUANK0bkqAb35QoAbQDWEEFEw4oZkPABmUVQF0WcJKgzZ8PMgIC+Avz2UjheuFBoyIzuyARsEJqK3rRQEAAeJDgAJqni0rLynko4KsnKmr6kpNQGUIThpSzlpep19IxuCfyc+oYA9P1QAJLWwAAW0NESlgC2YBIQsxA4bN6aAO4QAOTIUABGUpgS2VYA5lAT0PQemoQ5B1anOBdX9Y1QIWElqQiXk1AbsgAHR1ZDAKSIay6d4-TQdEhQQL8fyCQbojGYrFY-iDJzjTCpDZIEypQipDKQDAQbKg7H0hmDQTCaAAWRAsQgvkoUBh9ng8BY9EQ5yRaKGADl4CQWDh4JdwNB7nK1sooBE3gAiBo-TXq-YAKwgGCgEkwJEQkn4aGUwFhKR5fSgsxALQAjCw6AkWOzOb5OBRyDD+gAqKDZeW0eDLZ3wU72TBoYgOv4IiDAjNQENDcGQ6xppFtVHW23OjkIPZUKIQGIViDUHUpTR8gUsTX7QiITX+dgCF2c4GN5TAl3u6gtwVQduEABe3c4eIA6iTaHcKekqSRsvx+3XB41aMCrAA3SSYbItcefVtTjtzntQPGqGBQACiiEQSDXaQ3xq3glxRkgIxQD8UJcN4FkKAVSgYlEBMepUmGbZslNTAzCYQDgOA8URnqYASHmLdLnlDYRURQgFRECZiEiW1LSsX4AVPAp1UcbUDz1eBDT-NCLUkNo8Sjf5oCkWgIEQSJ7igM4IDtewIBpDs0AQqwzRwaBMEcK4LFmQgzHqZ1CQYAyrBE+0Ii+D5aEwM4cGISFZFBFlWA8FoVAAaXMVRFR-LJckBYARReSoEh0Xk6lMcxLGsLyQB8yBXFchRGnibQUQAktSjtIdSgAJi6NyDzwOpNVHRo3T1AAfKdypKPLNTaQxfTrXx+HCp06u8D1AsYLheUfMMI0BaNoFmOMtMTZM1VTBIM2BLMczkvNesRfwmrLFoCtW6BAwG0MRm2WZ6myZ4Lko8SbQeFjzxsaLJhBTNsygXMoR2sViyu+gy05PKeWrWsPAbA88uba9J2nLsex3csPDy-cfhHV0KqvfkIbvedeEfIZl3g1dEJ-TcaRh36EZSJGttRm9p3STHsagFAJGEuCTG3Xc4bJ4cTzPC9Gip9HZ3nenVHGT8NjJawJM-RAgA)