# How to create a generic type or interface for an object which all its properties are functions with different arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

Lets say I have these objects:

```
const actionsPost = {
    likePost: (id: number) => dispatch({type: Actions.like, payload: {id}}),
    addPost: (title: string, body: string) => dispatch({type: Actions.add, payload: {title, body}}),
    updatePost: (id: number, title: string, body: string) => dispatch({type: Actions.add, payload: {id, title, body}}),
}

const actionsComment = {
    likeComment: (id: number) => dispatch({type: Actions.like, payload: {id}}),
    addComent: (postId: number, body: string) => dispatch({type: Actions.comment, payload: {postId, body}}),
}
```

**How do I create a generic interface or type that matches both and any other one that I might come up with?**

I have tried this (assuming that dispatch always returns void) but didn't worked:

```
interface ActionsAggregator {
    [key: string]: <T extends any>(...args: T[]) => void
}
```

This one works but it is too broad and I lost code completion:

```
interface ActionsAggregator2 {
    [key: string]: Function
}
```

[Link to Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBkFMBcGdVgQwJ6gJKgBaIG6VNJpLPgPYBGAVpAMZwBcAUI5AHYCuAtqAIJ0CWpVvADejUBNAAbfgGtIAGlA1SnTm2hLEAE22MAvsxXDoobf1gAHRNBqZQAXlAAKHPVCJWyAJSOAfKAihozGsKaIAkKwAAqkYe580ILCPADmqQBOkKk2pBmOgeKSMvKx8S782u4cnOSQGb4OAeZWNnbOItDIlpAJkcIAdCWKoNbIUqQ67iKV%20vreCkUSOtpl0O7OSdBSvQjQGfysqUrkpNrI7mEHR43NFta2mB1dPX1JUQMrSmMTU4FbOxOZ2QcwWS1A7Es2hskDWG0q1S4dQySgBuyuh2OoFO50u%200xtzM9zaT063V2iWSsE%20um%20KF%20VUClVR-G2IxxIPmi2CoXC-VgAGFVOpWOtePy0plsrkMgAmApiSTSOSQIVqDTwxk1ZGEloPdpk17i96DYZ08aTRkzbSgxZKlZqjUuSxxaBoLVI%20pA3F7a6pXXEx7PclvKkDFTq0XmhnTF1hd3ezlg4IgUAACVIAHczKR0MosjCPKBUmx6vwaKBDtB6gAzCL4AjYUycEnEbGkQgeVjaLuoDtEfJCfCEGx5zj8VKYUwR-CQ0CZ1mYAD8zFTGGweAIB0gPcIxHwzkQsFgXExjdHepJHikmZQ8Cy0HYGWEoBwpEqvnI7FM5m0rAA5KYmZ5PIVTMFWtb1saVKSlkOTQHkhRKgA2vIFy%20piAC67gADwACqgJAAAe1bdvAnjIH4zgDDRiAZKksDuHhyGYYSb6VAYq5gHhmAWKAQ7ziB8BfqYGATGEyhnPgEaWDsJrgaKkE0PglJRLB0oIXKSGSKhkDoRiRzYaAABi7CsP0BhAA)

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: "This one works but it is too broad and I lost code completion" what kind of code completion would you expect for a generic type?

Comment: Also have you tried to work with the union type (`type actions = typeof actionsPost | typeof actionsComment`) ?

Comment: @JonasWilms #1 - By didn't work I mean I got some error like: "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'"

Comment: Please be more specific and [edit] the line were the error occured as well as the concrete error message into the question.

Comment: @JonasWilms #2 I would like to pass one of this objects to a function that expects this generic interface and by inference have some completion

Comment: There's nothing at that sandbox link... perhaps you can use the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org) and put the link in your question (not in a comment)

Comment: Ideally you should provide a [mcve] in plain text in the question, suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE (like the TS Playground).   Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbd19w) meet your needs?  There is no such interface as `ActionsAggregator` which both represents any possible object-holding-functions that also remembers which particular sort of object is assigned to it.  You really want a constraint and not an interface.  See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63362590/2887218) for more information.  If it doesn't meet your needs, please speak up soon.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for taking your time to help me, I've added the link to the typescript playground to the question itself

Comment: So, does [this code](//tsplay.dev/mbd19w) meet your needs or not?  Please refer to my previous comment about the lack of any specific interface in TypeScript that does what you want.  You cannot annotate a variable with an interface type and have the compiler remember anything more specific than the interface type.  See [this Q/A](//stackoverflow.com/q/60095712/2887218) for more information.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of that (perhaps with a link to [this](//stackoverflow.com/a/60100284/2887218) to explain why your generic function doesn't work) unless something is missing.

Comment: It's very unclear what your desired outcome is. Could you give some examples of both valid and invalid values for your desired type?